# $P$ is an matrix invertible Proof $|\lambda I-PBP^{-1}|=|\lambda I -B|$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I have this problem :

$P$ is an matrix invertible

Proof : $|\lambda I-PBP^{-1}|=|\lambda I -B|$

I'm not so sure about my answer, since I don't think I could use "double" determinant for example $||B||$ instand of $|B|$.

This is what I did (notice the notation):

$|\lambda I-PBP^{-1}|=|\lambda I-|P||B||P^{-1}|| = |\lambda I-|I||B|| =|\lambda I-B|$

I pretty sure I cannot use determinant that way, and since $|\lambda I-PBP^{-1}|\neq|\lambda I| -|P||B||P^{-1}$|

I don't find any determinant property to use in order to solve this problem.

Any Ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not quite right. You generally have the right idea though. Here's a hint:

$$|\lambda I-PBP^{-1}| = |P(\lambda I - B)P^{-1}|.$$

Comment: How is it generally the right idea?

Comment: @Cameron Williams Actually it also a part of the question but I managed to proof it so I didn't paste it here : $$|P(\lambda I - B)P^{-1}|=|P||(\lambda I - B)||P^{-1}| = |P||P^{-1}||(\lambda I - B)|=(\lambda I - B)$$

Comment: @Cameron Williams But I still don't understand how this help me with the problem, Can you please explain?

Comment: @JonasMeyer I meant using the inverses the way he did. He just did it in the wrong place.

Comment: @JaVaPG you basically proved it: $$|\lambda I - PBP^{-1}| = |P(\lambda I - B)P^{-1}| = |P||\lambda I - B||P^{-1}|.$$ Since $|P||P|^{-1} = 1$, you get that $$|\lambda I - PBP^{-1}| = |\lambda I - B|$$ which is exactly what you wanted to show.

Comment: @Cameron Williams I did proof that $|P||P^{-1}|=1$, But in this case the expression is $| \lambda I - PBP^{-1}|$ and I cannot use the commutative law here, in the previous I managed to reach to $|P|| \lambda I-B||P^{-1}|$ Which are all numbers and use the commutative law, but its unclear how you manage to conclude that in this case, I'll be glad if you could explain.

Comment: @JaVaPG Do you agree that $|A|$ is just a real number?

Comment: @Cameron Williams Yes, (I think you meant $P$)

Comment: @JaVaPG Since each of $|P|$, $|P^{-1}|$ and $|\lambda I-B|$ is a number, we can multiply them in any order we wish. So then $|\lambda I - PBP^{-1}| = |P||P^{-1}||\lambda I-B|$. It only remains to see that $|P||P^{-1}| = 1$. The reason this is the case is that $PP^{-1} = I$, so taking a determinant of both sides gives us $|PP^{-1}| = |I| = 1$. Determinants are multiplicative, so $|PP^{-1}| = |P||P^{-1}|$ and so $|P||P^{-1}| = 1$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Oh, now I see it now, you "pull out" the $B$ of the $PBP^{-1}$ in order to get $|\lambda I - B|$ and then it's like the previous expression meaning that $|\lambda I - B||P||P^{-1}|$

Comment: @JaVaPG no... That's not right. I'm factoring out $P$ on the left and $P^{-1}$ on the right.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Yes, I understand I skipped that part, since the commutative law,

Comment: @CameronWilliams Thank you, all clear!:)

Comment: @JaVaPG you're very welcome :)